# How to transmit beacon using altbeacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ble

I am working on Android app to transmit data by custom beacon,

here is my code :

```
public void transmitData() {
    mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(this, new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    // Transmit a beacon with Identifiers 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 2
    Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
            .setId2("2")
            .setId3("3")
            .setManufacturer(0x0335) // Choose a number of 0x00ff or less as some devices cannot detect beacons with a manufacturer code > 0x00ff
            .setTxPower(-59)
            .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))
            .build();

    int isDeviceSuprtTransmition = BeaconTransmitter.checkTransmissionSupported(MainActivity.this);
    Log.e("TransmitData=", "--transmitData--" + isDeviceSuprtTransmition);
    mBeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
    beaconManager.setDebug(true);

}
```

But I am not able to transmit data. I am not sure about setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6"), I am sending as this static, am I passing wrong or how to get this right one?

I am not able to see my beacon, in list of beacons,using nRF Connect in different tablet to find mac/Bluetooth address of my device.but my device bluetooth address not in the list.

Comment: What do you see for sDeviceSuprtTransmition?  Can you see the beacon on the other tablet using the Locate app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en

Comment: i heve list of bacons but i need transmit from my app,my bluetooth address not showing in list.can you please tell me what wrong i am doing and am i setting correct Id1,id2,id3?

Comment: Right, that's what I'm asking: Can you see your beacon transmitted with the above code using the Locate app running on a second device?

Comment: Yes,i can see. ID1,ID2,ID3 are same  and pawer is -56,Advertisement per second 10,Beaconformat : aa

Comment: OK, I think it works then.  I'm not sure why you are not seeing it on   nRF Connect .  I am not familiar with that app.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is ID1,ID2,ID3 i might be passing wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118576/discussion-between-davidgyoung-and-user).